ポインタを使わずに多様性を出す方法 ECSアーキテクチャ
質問内容
//std::vector<XXX*> componentList;ですが派生クラス部のTransform,Renderer,Script クラスに基底クラスを用意して派生クラスとして定義して、それを基底クラスのポインタ変数にnewして格納するという変数なのですが、その場合だと、メモリ上にバラバラの位置に格納されてしまいECSアーキテクチャの利点であるキャッシュヒット率が低下してしまします。なので、メモリ上に一列に並べる為にはすべて値型で.resize(100)などのメンバ関数を使って、メモリ上に一列に確保する必要があります。なので提示コードでは派生クラスとしては定義していないのですが、下記の現状の問題部をどうやって解決すればいいのでしょうか？
コードについて
提示コードですが、ゲーム開発で大量のオブジェクトを効率よく処理するECSアーキテクチャを実装するためにまずはコンソール出力で簡易的にテストしている試作の実験コードです。
また、意味もなく継承や基底クラスなどを用意しますが、それも試作なのでその辺は色々おかしいです。
ArcheType: Chunkをまとめるクラス
Chunk: ComponentDataの複数の塊です。並列処理を後々サポートしたいので取りえず用意
class Script: は自分で記述したコードを仮定しています。複数ある予定です。
現状の問題
システム管理クラス(SystemManager)ではどのようにComponentDataクラス継承した Voxel,Characterを処理するればいいのでしょうか？
値型を持ちいる必要があるので(キャッシュヒット率を高める為)、
システム部ではループ処理をして欲しいコンポーネントデータを参照するといったコードの書き方はできません、また、自作のコンポーネントデータとシステムが増えていくと
いちいち個別に色々記述していては、混乱の元なので、シンプルにしたいです。
コンポーネント指向ではComponentクラスを継承したTransformクラスなどを
std::vector<Component*>として受けてそれを派生クラスでオーバーライド済みの.Update()関数でループ処理するという形式が取れません
問題
システム管理部でそれぞれのコンポーネントデータに対して処理をいちいちすべて個々に記述しないといけない。
知りたいこと
自作のコンポーネントデータとシステムが増えもシンプルに保つ方法
前提
キャッシュヒット率を高めるため、メモリ上で一列データを並べる。
考えた事

上記に記述しましたがポインタがを用いる　これは間違えですメモリ上ではバラバラの場所に確保されます。
それぞれシステムを記述する、これは規模が大きくなったときに面倒です。
コンポーネントデータを組みをビット列で表す方法を考えましたが、ビット列を元に変数をnewなどで確保すると
メモリ上でバラバラの場所に確保されて、意味なくなります。
3番の上記のビット列で表す方法を何かに用いれそうな気がしてなりません。

調べたこと

"ECSアーキテクチャ C++" などの言葉で検索をしましたがUnityで使われるアーキテクチャなのでC++での今回の困りごとはヒットしません。
Unity ECS上での内部表現を参考にコードを作成

参考ページ
古典的ゲームループからECSアーキテクチャまで
https://zenn.dev/rita0222/articles/c22a8367e31b4d5f4eeb
試作コード (利用ライブラリ: glmのみ)
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

/*############################################################################
# 基底クラス  
##############################################################################*/

/*######################################
#  ComponentData base class
########################################*/
class ComponentData
{
public:

 //std::vector<XXX*> componentList;

    ComponentData()
    {
        std::cout << "Component Created" << std::endl;
    }

};

/*######################################
#  System base class
########################################*/
class System
{
public:
    
    System()
    {
        std::cout << "System Created" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void Update() = 0;
};

/*######################################
#  Chunk base class
########################################*/
class Chunk
{
public:


    Chunk()
    {
        std::cout << "Chunk Created" << std::endl;
    }
};

/*######################################
#  ArcheType base class
########################################*/
class ArcheType
{
public:
    ArcheType()
    {
        std::cout << "ArcheType Created" << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<Chunk*> chunkList;

};



/*############################################################################
# 派生クラス  
##############################################################################*/

/*######################################
#  Transform Component
########################################*/
class Transform
{
public:

    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 rotate;
    glm::vec3 scale;

    Transform()
    {
        std::cout << "Transform Created" << std::endl;
    }


};

/*######################################
#  Mesh Component
########################################*/
class Renderer
{
public:

    glm::vec4 color;
    
    Renderer()
    {
        std::cout << "Mesh Created" << std::endl;
    }
};

/*######################################
#  Script Component
########################################*/
class Script
{
public:

    int Hp = 100;
    int Mp = 100;

    Script()
    {
        std::cout << "Script Created" << std::endl;
    }
};

/*######################################
#  Voxel ComponentData
########################################*/
class Voxel : public ComponentData
{
public:

    Transform transform;
    Renderer renderer;

    Voxel() : ComponentData()
    {
        std::cout << "Voxel Created" << std::endl;
    }
};

/*######################################
#  Character ComponentData
########################################*/
class Character : public ComponentData
{
public:

    Transform transform;
    Renderer renderer;
    Script script;

    Character() : ComponentData()
    {
        std::cout << "Character Created" << std::endl;
    }
};


/*######################################
#  Render System
########################################*/
class RendererSystem : public System
{
public:
    
    RendererSystem()
    {
        std::cout << "Render System Created" << std::endl;
    }

    void Update() override
    {
        std::cout << "Render System Updated" << std::endl;
    }

};

/*######################################
#  Movement System
########################################*/
class MovementSystem : public System
{
public:
    
    MovementSystem()
    {
        std::cout << "Movement System Created" << std::endl;
    }

    void Update() override
    {
        std::cout << "Movement System Updated" << std::endl;
    }

};

/*######################################
#  Character System
########################################*/
class CharacterSystem : public System
{
public:
    
    CharacterSystem()
    {
        std::cout << "Character System Created" << std::endl;
    }

    void Update() override
    {
        std::cout << "Character System Updated" << std::endl;
    }

};

/*######################################
#  Voxel_Chunk chunk
########################################*/
class Voxel_Chunk : public Chunk
{
public:

    std::vector<Voxel> list;
    
    Voxel_Chunk() : Chunk()
    {
        std::cout << "Voxel_Chunk Created" << std::endl;
    }



};

/*######################################
#  Character_Chunk chunk
########################################*/
class Character_Chunk : public Chunk
{
public:

    std::vector<Character> list;
    
    Character_Chunk() : Chunk()
    {
        std::cout << "Character_Chunk Created" << std::endl;
    }



};


/*############################################################################
# その他
##############################################################################*/

/*######################################
#  SystemManager
########################################*/
class SystemManager : public System
{
public:
    
    static std::vector<System*> systemList;
    static std::vector<ArcheType*> archeTypeList;

    SystemManager()
    {
        std::cout << "SystemManager Created" << std::endl;
    }

/*
    void Update() override
    {
        
    }
*/
    static void AddSystem(System* system)
    {
        systemList.push_back(system);
    }

/*
    static void AddArcheType()
    {
        systemList.push_back();
    }
*/

};

std::vector<System*> SystemManager::systemList;
std::vector<ArcheType*> SystemManager::archeTypeList;

/*######################################
#  EntityManager
########################################*/
class EntityManager
{
public:



};



/*######################################
#  Entity
########################################*/
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity()
    {
        std::cout << "Entity Created" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SystemManager::AddSystem(new MovementSystem());
    SystemManager::AddSystem(new CharacterSystem());
    SystemManager::AddSystem(new RendererSystem());

    return 0;
}


「Entity Component System c++」あたりで検索しても分からないでしょうか。

既に書いたコードを実行したら性能に不満があるほど遅いということなら、どこが遅いのか実測してから対策に手を付けましょう。まだ実行すらしていない時点で遅そう？と懸念しているのであれば、それは典型的「早すぎる最適化は諸悪の根源」ですね。

案A：静的多態性を使う
注意：

ECSアーキテクチャーもゲームプログラミングも知らないため、質問者の真の目的である処理速度の向上に効果があるかは不明です（約20倍も速度向上するなんて記事もありますが、実際のゲームにおいて連続したオブジェクトを都合良く操作することがあるのか不明）。
ECSアーキテクチャーのクラス構造もコンポーネント指向のクラス構造も回答の本質ではないため、ほとんど無視しています。
エラー処理は、省略しています。
静的多態性のデメリットに関しては、自分で調べてください。

解説：
C++は、仮想関数を使った動的多態性だけでなく、テンプレートを使った静的多態性を使えるため、コンポーネントクラスを継承関係にする必要は無く、関数のシグネチャーが一致していれば呼び出せます。
C++の標準ライブラリでも、コンテナー（データ）とアルゴリズム（ロジック）が分離されていますが、データクラスの継承関係は不要です。
サンプルコード：
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#if defined __GNUC__
#define PRETTY_FUNCTION __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
#elif defined _MSC_VER
#define PRETTY_FUNCTION __FUNCSIG__
#else
#define PRETTY_FUNCTION __func__
#endif

template<int Type>
class Component
{
public:
    void Update() {
        std::cout << PRETTY_FUNCTION << "\n";
    }
};

using ComponentA = Component<0>;
using ComponentB = Component<1>;
using ComponentC = Component<2>;

using ComponentArrayA = std::vector<ComponentA>;
using ComponentArrayB = std::vector<ComponentB>;
using ComponentArrayC = std::vector<ComponentC>;

template<int Type>
class System
{
public:
    template<class ComponentType>
    void Update(std::vector<ComponentType> &components)
    {
        std::cout << PRETTY_FUNCTION << ": begin" << "\n";

        for ( auto &component : components ) {
            component.Update();
        }

        std::cout << PRETTY_FUNCTION << ": end" << "\n";
    }
};

using SystemA = System<0>;
using SystemB = System<1>;
using SystemC = System<2>;

int main(void)
{
    ComponentArrayA componentsA;
    ComponentArrayB componentsB;
    ComponentArrayC componentsC;

    componentsA.emplace_back();
    componentsA.emplace_back();
    componentsB.emplace_back();
    componentsB.emplace_back();
    componentsC.emplace_back();
    componentsC.emplace_back();

    SystemA systemA;
    SystemB systemB;
    SystemC systemC;

    systemA.Update(componentsA);
    systemA.Update(componentsB);
    systemA.Update(componentsC);

    systemB.Update(componentsA);
    systemB.Update(componentsB);
    systemB.Update(componentsC);

    systemC.Update(componentsA);
    systemC.Update(componentsB);
    systemC.Update(componentsC);
}

実行結果(Visual Studio 2022)：
void __cdecl System<0>::Update<class Component<0>>(class std::vector<class Component<0>,class std::allocator<class Component<0> > > &): begin
void __cdecl Component<0>::Update(void)
void __cdecl Component<0>::Update(void)
void __cdecl System<0>::Update<class Component<0>>(class std::vector<class Component<0>,class std::allocator<class Component<0> > > &): end
void __cdecl System<0>::Update<class Component<1>>(class std::vector<class Component<1>,class std::allocator<class Component<1> > > &): begin
void __cdecl Component<1>::Update(void)
void __cdecl Component<1>::Update(void)
void __cdecl System<0>::Update<class Component<1>>(class std::vector<class Component<1>,class std::allocator<class Component<1> > > &): end
void __cdecl System<0>::Update<class Component<2>>(class std::vector<class Component<2>,class std::allocator<class Component<2> > > &): begin
void __cdecl Component<2>::Update(void)
void __cdecl Component<2>::Update(void)
void __cdecl System<0>::Update<class Component<2>>(class std::vector<class Component<2>,class std::allocator<class Component<2> > > &): end
void __cdecl System<1>::Update<class Component<0>>(class std::vector<class Component<0>,class std::allocator<class Component<0> > > &): begin
void __cdecl Component<0>::Update(void)
void __cdecl Component<0>::Update(void)
void __cdecl System<1>::Update<class Component<0>>(class std::vector<class Component<0>,class std::allocator<class Component<0> > > &): end
void __cdecl System<1>::Update<class Component<1>>(class std::vector<class Component<1>,class std::allocator<class Component<1> > > &): begin
void __cdecl Component<1>::Update(void)
void __cdecl Component<1>::Update(void)
void __cdecl System<1>::Update<class Component<1>>(class std::vector<class Component<1>,class std::allocator<class Component<1> > > &): end
void __cdecl System<1>::Update<class Component<2>>(class std::vector<class Component<2>,class std::allocator<class Component<2> > > &): begin
void __cdecl Component<2>::Update(void)
void __cdecl Component<2>::Update(void)
void __cdecl System<1>::Update<class Component<2>>(class std::vector<class Component<2>,class std::allocator<class Component<2> > > &): end
void __cdecl System<2>::Update<class Component<0>>(class std::vector<class Component<0>,class std::allocator<class Component<0> > > &): begin
void __cdecl Component<0>::Update(void)
void __cdecl Component<0>::Update(void)
void __cdecl System<2>::Update<class Component<0>>(class std::vector<class Component<0>,class std::allocator<class Component<0> > > &): end
void __cdecl System<2>::Update<class Component<1>>(class std::vector<class Component<1>,class std::allocator<class Component<1> > > &): begin
void __cdecl Component<1>::Update(void)
void __cdecl Component<1>::Update(void)
void __cdecl System<2>::Update<class Component<1>>(class std::vector<class Component<1>,class std::allocator<class Component<1> > > &): end
void __cdecl System<2>::Update<class Component<2>>(class std::vector<class Component<2>,class std::allocator<class Component<2> > > &): begin
void __cdecl Component<2>::Update(void)
void __cdecl Component<2>::Update(void)
void __cdecl System<2>::Update<class Component<2>>(class std::vector<class Component<2>,class std::allocator<class Component<2> > > &): end


案B：動的多態性のままoperator new, deleteを置き換えて、自分で連続領域に割り当てる
注意：

ECSアーキテクチャーもゲームプログラミングも知らないため、質問者の真の目的である処理速度の向上に効果があるかは不明です（約20倍も速度向上するなんて記事もありますが、実際のゲームにおいて連続したオブジェクトを都合良く操作することがあるのか不明）。
ECSアーキテクチャーのクラス構造もコンポーネント指向のクラス構造も回答の本質ではないため、ほとんど無視しています。
エラー処理は、省略しています。

解説：
C++は、クラス毎にoperator new, deleteを置き換えることができるため、動的多態性のままでも自分で連続領域に割り当てることができます。
コンポーネントクラスでのoperator new, deleteの定義をする／しないだけを切り替えれば、連続領域に割り当てるか否かを簡単に切り替えられるため、それだけで本当に処理速度が向上するか否かの実験がし易いでしょう。
サンプルコード：
アロケーター側:
#ifndef ARRAY_ALLOCATOR_HPP
#define ARRAY_ALLOCATOR_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <new>

template<class T_ObjectType, typename T_NumberType, T_NumberType T_ObjectNumber = std::numeric_limits<std::uint_least16_t>::max()>
class ArrayAllocator
{
    struct Object
    {
        std::uint8_t m_bytes[sizeof(T_ObjectType)];
    };

    std::vector<Object> m_objects;
    std::vector<T_NumberType> m_indexes;
    T_NumberType m_firstAvailableObjectIdx;
    T_NumberType m_availableObjectNumber;

public:
    ArrayAllocator()
        : m_objects{T_ObjectNumber}
        , m_indexes(T_ObjectNumber)
        , m_firstAvailableObjectIdx{0u}
        , m_availableObjectNumber{T_ObjectNumber}
    {
        for ( T_NumberType nextObjectIdx{1u}; nextObjectIdx < m_indexes.size(); ++nextObjectIdx )
        {
            m_indexes[nextObjectIdx - 1u] = nextObjectIdx;
        }
    }

    void *allocate()
    {
        if ( m_availableObjectNumber == 0u ) throw std::bad_alloc();

        Object *nextObjectPtr{&m_objects[m_firstAvailableObjectIdx]};
        m_firstAvailableObjectIdx = m_indexes[m_firstAvailableObjectIdx];
        --m_availableObjectNumber;
        return nextObjectPtr;
    }

    void deallocate(void *objectVoidPtr)
    {
        unsigned char *objectCharPtr{static_cast<unsigned char *>(objectVoidPtr)};
        unsigned char *beginObjectCharPtr{reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(m_objects.data())};
        T_NumberType deallocateIdx = static_cast<T_NumberType>((objectCharPtr - beginObjectCharPtr) / sizeof(Object));
        m_indexes[deallocateIdx] = m_firstAvailableObjectIdx;
        m_firstAvailableObjectIdx = deallocateIdx;
        ++m_availableObjectNumber;
    }
};

#endif // ARRAY_ALLOCATOR_HPP

アロケーターを使用する側：
#include "ArrayAllocator.hpp"
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#if defined __GNUC__
#define PRETTY_FUNCTION __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
#elif defined _MSC_VER
#define PRETTY_FUNCTION __FUNCSIG__
#else
#define PRETTY_FUNCTION __func__
#endif

class Component
{
    using ComponentArrayType = std::vector<Component *>;
    static ComponentArrayType s_components;

public:
    template<class SubComponentType>
    static Component *AddComponent()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<SubComponentType> subComponentPtr{new SubComponentType()};
        s_components.push_back(subComponentPtr.get());
        return subComponentPtr.release();
    }

    virtual ~Component() = default;
    virtual void Update() = 0;
};

Component::ComponentArrayType Component::s_components;

template<int SubComponentType>
class SubComponent : public Component
{
    using ArrayAllocatorType = ArrayAllocator<SubComponent, std::uint_least16_t>;
    static ArrayAllocatorType s_allocator;

    double d[3];

public:
    static void *operator new(std::size_t size)
    {
        assert(size == sizeof(SubComponent));
        return s_allocator.allocate();
    }

    static void operator delete(void *objectPtr)
    {
        s_allocator.deallocate(objectPtr);
    }

    void Update() override
    {
        std::cout << PRETTY_FUNCTION << ": begin" << "\n";
        std::cout << "this = " << this << "\n";
        std::cout << PRETTY_FUNCTION << ": end" << "\n";
    }
};

template<int SubComponentType>
typename SubComponent<SubComponentType>::ArrayAllocatorType SubComponent<SubComponentType>::s_allocator;

using SubComponentA = SubComponent<0>;
typename SubComponentA::ArrayAllocatorType SubComponentA::s_allocator;
using SubComponentB = SubComponent<1>;
typename SubComponentB::ArrayAllocatorType SubComponentB::s_allocator;
using SubComponentC = SubComponent<2>;
typename SubComponentC::ArrayAllocatorType SubComponentC::s_allocator;

int main()
{
    try {
        for ( std::size_t i{0u}; i < 3; ++i )
        {
            Component::AddComponent<SubComponentA>()->Update();
            Component::AddComponent<SubComponentB>()->Update();
            Component::AddComponent<SubComponentC>()->Update();
        }
    }
    catch ( std::exception &e )
    {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }
}

実行結果(Visual Studio 2022)：
void __cdecl SubComponent<0>::Update(void): begin
this = 00000204E7496080
void __cdecl SubComponent<0>::Update(void): end
void __cdecl SubComponent<1>::Update(void): begin
this = 00000204E76A4080
void __cdecl SubComponent<1>::Update(void): end
void __cdecl SubComponent<2>::Update(void): begin
this = 00000204E78B2080
void __cdecl SubComponent<2>::Update(void): end
void __cdecl SubComponent<0>::Update(void): begin
this = 00000204E74960A0
void __cdecl SubComponent<0>::Update(void): end
void __cdecl SubComponent<1>::Update(void): begin
this = 00000204E76A40A0
void __cdecl SubComponent<1>::Update(void): end
void __cdecl SubComponent<2>::Update(void): begin
this = 00000204E78B20A0
void __cdecl SubComponent<2>::Update(void): end
void __cdecl SubComponent<0>::Update(void): begin
this = 00000204E74960C0
void __cdecl SubComponent<0>::Update(void): end
void __cdecl SubComponent<1>::Update(void): begin
this = 00000204E76A40C0
void __cdecl SubComponent<1>::Update(void): end
void __cdecl SubComponent<2>::Update(void): begin
this = 00000204E78B20C0
void __cdecl SubComponent<2>::Update(void): end

